# Remove pin icon from filters pane

Tags: sharepoint-online, filter, modern-experience, sorting

Is it possible to hide or remove the **pin icon** from filters pane which would prevent users to click on it or remove the pinned column from the filter pane by any chance? Such as making it default pinned menu?

Some users click on it by mistake and it removes the column from the filters pane, unfortunately.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We can create a SPFx Applications Customiser to inject the following CSS style to site to achieve it.

```
.od-FilterSectionHeader-sideCommands button[name='Unpin']{
    display:none !important;
}
```

**Solution**: [SPFx Applications Customiser CSS Injection](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/master/samples/react-application-injectcss)